# Geoserver - layer security: writing while no reading

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

I have a postgis layer hosted by Geoserver with the aim to collect public opinions in it. So the layer uses WFST and has to be editable. However, I want to limit a reading access to secure the opinions which have already come so they cannot be seen by anyone.

In brief, what I need is:

- read = admin
- write = everyone

I try to adjust the layer security file.

```
#Wed Feb 23 08:33:53 UTC 2022
*.*.r=*
*.*.w=*
my_workspace.my_layer.r=ADMIN
my_workspace.my_layer.w=*
mode=HIDE
```

And it doesn't work, geoserver denies any writing to the layer. It seems that the reading rule is overriding the writing rule.

If I set `my_workspace.my_layer.r=*` it works fine with writing to the layer, but my layer is visible to anyone. I there any workaround?

Here is a snippet from the logs if it can help:

```
Request: getServiceInfo
2022-02-23 09:21:14,820 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Feature type 'my_layer' is not available: 
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:199)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:98)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:147)
    .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a layer that can be written to but not read is probably counter intuitive to any client, so it might be the case that GeoServer does not support it.

Have you considered any alternative solutions? You could for instance set up a filter on the layer "Restrict the features on layer by CQL filter" on the layer definition page in Geoserver. Set a condition that will be false for all features, like "1=0". The result is that the layer can be read, but you won't get any features when reading. As this is done server side the end-user can not circumvent the filter.

And then of course you set up another layer without the filter for the admin users.

Another option would be working with two database tables and create a trigger that moves all insertions to another table.

Comment: Tnank you. I went for option #2 setting two tables and a trigger inbetween. It copies the incoming data to the secured table and deletes it from the piblished one.